# Help with RubyGems (the package manager)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I really need help with Rubygems (that's the package manager for ruby). Since I'm behind a proxy, I've given up all hope of it working automatically, so I had to download a *lot* of packages manually and install them for rails to install. Now, I'm getting an error message:

```
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (...)
```

Once again, I manually downloaded rubygems-1.3.2.gem and installed it, however, it still doesn't work and `gem -v` shows `1.3.1`. Help. Also, I can assure it that unless gem has HTTP1.1 Auth Proxy support, there is no way it by itself will be able to contact its server...

Comment: nb. A direct implication of the proxy problem is that `gem update --system` will probably not work...

Comment: What operating system are you using?
How did you install the rubygems packages?

Comment: I'm using Windows. I got rubygems through the big all-in-one installer for Ruby. The other packages I downloaded from the site and then installed by using : `gem install package-name.gem`

Answer (score 0):

Before running rubygems commands, you should try something like (for windows)

```
set http_proxy=user:password@ip:port
```

Or export for linux, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one can simply download the source tarballs, untar them and use `setup.rb` to install the update. [More information on it here.](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3)

Answer (score 0):

I did [this](http://trevoke.net/blog/2009/09/09/rubygems-through-a-proxy-with-authentication/) and was very pleased with the result (no problem!).